QUERY() como puedo eljir varias columnas ala vez si tener que especificar cada una
Buenas tardes tengo esta formula:
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url_hoja_cálculo";"Hoja 1!A:Z");"select A,B,C,D, F,G,H ";1)
Existe alguna manera para reducir la llamada select como por ejemplo
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url_hoja_cálculo";"Hoja 1!A:Z");"select A:D,F:H ";1)
// esto no funciona
Un saludo.
